# How can I determine the group scope of groups in my Windows token?

Tags: active-directory, active-directory-group

I want to determine the types of all of the groups in my security token.  I know how to do this by looking it up in AD using S.DS (or S.SD.AM or S.DS.P).  Is there any other way, that doesn't involve 160 calls to ADSI, because it's not exactly performant?  :-)

Answer (score 0):

By the time you see the token, any of the SID compression that happens with certain group types is abstracted away so I can't think of a way to figure this out without going back to AD. What are you trying to accomplish in the end?

Comment: We have problems with token size.  But I've tried creating an account which should have the token size problem and I can still logon and access an ASP.NET web page.  So, I've used WindowsIdentity/Principal stuff to display the groups on that page.  It'd be useful to know what types they were, then I could calculate the expected token size to help identify token size problems.

Comment: I think you're going to need to go back to AD and gather this information on a per-group basis. You could batch the requests by building OR filters with all the group info.